# SQL query to return a chain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy, chaining

I have a table that tracks changes. One column is called `beforename` and the other `aftername`.

Some sample data might be:

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| b | c |
| c | d |

I am trying to write a query that will self reference itself in such a way as to return the changes ie:

```
a -> b -> c -> d (the arrows are just for notation here)
```

Is this possible to do in SQL?

My database is SQL Server

Comment: yes. using [recursive cte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions)

Comment: I suspect you will need a proper sequence like a datetime or an identity.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a recursive common table expression (CTE);

```
WITH cte(Root, Level, Parent, Child) AS (
  SELECT Parent, 0, Parent, Child FROM Table1 
     WHERE Parent NOT IN (SELECT Child FROM Table1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte.Root, cte.Level + 1, t1.Parent, t1.Child 
  FROM cte 
  JOIN Table1 t1 
     ON cte.Child = t1.Parent AND cte.Level < 10
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY Root, Level;
```

Basically, a recursive CTE uses a base case (find all starting points). THis one uses;

```
SELECT Parent, 0, Parent, Child FROM Table1 
     WHERE Parent NOT IN (SELECT Child FROM Table1)
```

...which finds all parents, that is rows where the parent is never mentioned in the table as a child. It then sets those parent as a "Root" and sets level to 0.

It then proceeds to find the child rows for that root using;

```
SELECT cte.Root, cte.Level + 1, t1.Parent, t1.Child 
  FROM cte 
  JOIN Table1 t1 
     ON cte.Child = t1.Parent AND cte.Level < 10
```

...which basically just finds the next child (a row which has this rows child as a parent) while keeping the root and increasing level by 1.

It also limits the recursion to 10 levels just in case there is a loop in the data.

[A dbfiddle to test with](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6175aa461c7cc689d7fb4e112aa41a72)